# Retrieve an overview of all countries that have at least one city, how many cities they have. and the average population of these cities

Tags: mysql

another day and another mysql problem, ive been scratching my head with this question for quite some while now.

My task is through a database called "world" is to retrive and overview of countries with atleast one city, how many cities they have and the average population of these cities. i would also like to sort the average population by using " (AS AverageCityPopulation)" and the number of cities with "(AS NumberOfCities)".

ive just started to learn about join, left join and right join aswell and i am pretty certain that i have to use one of those 3 to complete the task. im still trying to find a helpful way to memorize when to use those 3 ***(if you have a tip please leave it down below)***.

anyways, the data should be sorted like this i feel like

| countrycode | countryname |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

| cityname | citycountrycode |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

| averagecitypop | numberofcities |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

of course the data should be displayed sideways but it is a bit hard to make it work in stackoverflow. anyways, i have tried with multiple queries for now, but still havent found the answer. the closest i got to was the entire avg population of a city in Aruba

my current query is:

```
SELECT 
country.name,
country.code,
city.name,
AVG(city.population) AS averageCityPop,
city.countrycode
FROM

world.city
    right JOIN
world.country ON city.CountryCode = country.code

where city.CountryCode > 1
```

again i am relativly new, so any thesis or curriculum is appriciated as answers in this post and answers to my question, if you also know any good youtube channels or forums where its helpful to learn mysql it would be great!

thanks for any helpful answers <3

here are a few screenshots about the two tables im trying to connect
[world.city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38xV6.png)

[world.country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzzwc.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, please share how your problem is related to [tag:mysql-workbench] itself

Comment: @NicoHaase to be fair i dont know how it is related to mysql-workbench, but my professor told us if we were to use stackoverflow we should use the tags mysql and mysql workbench, i can add a few screenshots to the post about the database and its structure?

Comment: Please don't add screenshots for stuff that is pure text, like the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements

Comment: @NicoHaase ive added screenshots of the two databases im trying to join together, i dont know if it helps you much, even if you cant answer my question because of how clunckly its asked. i would appriciate if you have any other sources on the internet that can help with mysql

Comment: **Please don't add screenshots for stuff that is pure text** - just share the data in a format that others can directly use to fiddle around with your data. In the end, it's **your** homework and not ours

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that the database I use is MySQL sample database - World.
For beginners: both tables have primary keys (for table country, it is 'code', for table city, it is 'id'), so it's enough to use inner joins.

```
SELECT co.code AS country_code,
       co.name AS country_name, 
       COUNT(*) AS num_cities,
       AVG(ci.population) AS avg_city_pop
FROM country co INNER JOIN city ci ON (co.code = ci.countrycode)
GROUP BY co.code;
```

Or if you want to show the name of each city:

```
SELECT co.code AS country_code,
       co.name AS country_name,
       ci.name AS city_name,
       COUNT(*) OVER w AS num_cities,
       AVG(ci.population) OVER w AS avg_city_pop
FROM country co INNER JOIN city ci ON (co.code = ci.countrycode)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY co.code);
```

Comment: thank you @aphoridite! but why do you use inner join instead of left join or right join?

Comment: @benny inner join returns only matching records, which means if a country appears in the join results, it must have at least one matching city. That's enough to complete the task. If you want to find countries that have no cities and mark their 'num_city' as 0, then you can use the left join (the right join is equivalent to the left join in some sense).